# Boost sub_match Throws std::length_error Exception

Tags: c++, regex, exception, boost

I am using Boost Regex. I have the following code (simplified):

```
bool search_for_match(const string& data)
{
  boost::smatch results;
  if(boost::regex_search(data, results, my_regex))
  {
    if(results["REVISION"].matched)
    {
      std::string the_submatch = results["REVISION"].str();
      std::cout << the_submatch << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

`my_regex` is a successfully compiled regular expression. The line where I assign `the_submatch` to `results["SUBMATCH_TWO"].str()` throws an exception of type `std::length_error` and `what()` prints out `basic_string::_S_create`.

Reading the documentation on Boost sub_match, it states that if `matched` is true then the iterators will be set. Why is this blowing up? The `data` string is not going out of scope here but it sure seems to act like the iterators are undefined or the data string has gone out of scope which renders the iterators bad. The documentation also states that if `matched` is false, then just an empty string is returned. So, I know matched has to be true but the iterators are all garbled up or something.

Here is the regular expression:

```
(?<FLIGHT_ID>[[:alnum:]]+)
\t[ ]{1,2}
(?<BEACON_CODE>[[:alnum:]]+)
\t[ ]{1,2}
((?=[A-Z]{2,5}[ ])(?<DEPARTURE_POINT>[A-Z]{2,5})[ ](?<DESTINATION_POINT>[A-Z]{2,5})|(?<DEPARTURE_POINT>[^\t ]{1,13}))
\t?[ ]{1,2}                                                                       
(?<ROUTE1>[[:print:]]+)
(?: \t[ ]+ (?<EDCT>[[:alnum:]]+) )?
\r\n
(?<REVISION>\d+)?
(?: \s+ (?<STRIP_ORIGINATOR>[[:alnum:]]+) )?
\r\n
(?<AIRCRAFT_TYPE>[[:alnum:]/ ]+)
\t[ ]{1,2}
P(?<DEPARTURE_TIME>\d+)
(?: [ ][ ]\t[ ]{1,2} )?
(?: (?<ROUTE2>[[:print:]]+) )?
(?: \t[ ][ ] )?
(?: (?<EDCT_TIME>\d+) )?
\r\n
\n
(?<COMPUTER_ID>[[:alnum:]]+)
\t[ ]{1,2}
(?<ALTITUDE>VFR/\d+|\d+)
(?: [\t ]*  (?<ROUTE3>[[:print:]]+) )?
\r\n?
```

As you can see, the REVISION named subgroup is optional. That is why I check for `matched` to be true. I compile `my_regex` like so:

```
boost::regex my_regex;
void compile_pattern(const string& pattern)
{
  try
  {
    boost::regex compiled_expression(pattern, boost::regex::mod_x);
    my_regex = compiled_expression;
  }
  catch(boost::regex_error& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I read in the entire file that contains that regular expression and store it into a string and pass that into the `compile_patterns()` function. That seems to work just fine since I do not see an exception thrown so it seems like a valid regular expression to me.

Comment: I'll include it here. It is gigantic... hold on a second.

Comment: Well, perhaps include a simple regex that demonstrates the problem for you (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), or indeed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a183bef8dea1f13 - _[I never approach a SO question without actually working code. I didn't include it in the answer this time because it isn't relevant to my analysis.]_

Comment: Hah. That's a wild regex. Do you have a grammar spec or some samples? I'd like to try something else (tomorrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual culprit leading to this error is when constructing a `std::string` from a `nullptr` char*.

In your case that should not be possible because all iterator ranges are expressed as iterators into the source string. What, then, seems to be the most logical explanation is when the problem is outside the code shown.

For example, you could be passing a stale reference to a `std::string const` as the `data` argument. This would invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which can manifest in many ways.

It's not an unlikely scenario when interpreting memory that used to hold a `std::string` instance as such an object, when that object no longer exists (it has been destructed, or the memory might even already have been repurposed) to lead to an iterator that dereferences to a null pointer.

Comment: It seems weird to me that the `data` argument could be stale but yet the Boost Regex engine can still match against it. But, I suppose with undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: Indeed. I'd check it. The source of the UB could even be elsewhere. Are you using checkers (asan/ubsan or valgrind etc?)

Comment: Guess I need to use valgrind more. I don't hardly ever use it because I use a lot of third party stuff and it just pukes warnings at me. For example, Boost barfs out all kinds of stuff at me when I use valgrind on anything that ties into Boost.

Comment: That's not a good sign. As you can probably tell, I use Boost intensively, daily and for everything. Even all my [SO] code samples run under asan/valgrind (with the exception of Boost Coroutine, though it's possible to enable valgrind for it during build).

Comment: In this case, you should certainly be able to isolate the part of the program that you **think** contains the error. If anything, it might **prove** that the error is elsewhere, but my own [suggested SSCCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a183bef8dea1f13) runs cleanly under valgrind. There's a start! This is the proper way to circle your bug: http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/

Comment: Read the article you linked. I obviously and leaving out 99% of my total software. I'll try and write something small to reproduce the problem and then post all of it here.

Comment: Figured it out. However, I am having an issue on getting my Regex to mathc correctly. I'll post another question on that.

Comment: Remember my [invitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291061/boost-sub-match-throws-stdlength-error-exception/48291212?noredirect=1#comment83567939_48291061). What cause did you find? Was it indeed a source of UB elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah. I was initializing a string from a vector. I then returned a reference to that string which would then go out of scope by the time i would use it which made all kinds of weird things happen. I also got my Regex fixed. In the original post, you can see where I use a conditional in the Regex and I used <DEPARTURE_POINT> twice. I plugged this into www.regex101.com and it gave me an error stating you cannot use the same name in a named capture group. I assumed that Boost would throw an exception at me but it doesn't. Instead, it just causes weird behavior.

Comment: I thought that the alternation in the conditional would allow for <DEPARTURE_POINT> to be defined one way if the conditional evaluated to true and defined another way if the conditional evaluated to false. But, instead, you have to use a different name for the named capture group in the conditional. If you use the same one, it causes weird things to happen. My assumption is the Regex engine overwrites some internal structures when this happens. The www.regex101.com website highlighted it as an error.

Comment: Good findings. Goes to show, regexen are - too often - bug traps. Good luck with your project.